# Which is the cache I have to clear to refresh list of view blocks?

Tags: blocks, caching

I created a new block (a view block) but it is not available to use in other modules (like panels). If I clear all cache then it shows up.

I don't want to clear all caches but only the right one to get the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use **Drush** you can clearly see there are cache for **block** and **views**. Clear both these cache and you will get the required result

Comment: I tried that but didn't work. Only works if I clear all caches.

Comment: If you have a panel, containing a block display of a view, you're doing it wrong (probably). You should be using a content-pane display of your view for use in the panel.

That said, only the outer-most cache is used, so if you cache the panel, and cache the block inside the panel, and cache the view inside the block, only the panels-cache is actually used.

Answer (score 1):

Block cache is stored in the `cache_block` bin.

The cache ID is decided by the [`_block_get_cache_id()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.module/function/_block_get_cache_id/7) function, which you would use like so:

```
$block = block_load($module_name, $delta);
$cid = _block_get_cache_id($block);
cache_clear_all('cache_block', $cid);
```

It's worth bearing in mind that advanced modules like ctools and panels keep their own cache, so if the above doesn't work, have a look through the code for those modules and see what they use instead of the standard block cache to store data. Then clear that one instead.